# How to add onclick event to limesurvey submit button

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

I want to know how to add a javascript click event to limesurvey submit button.
[lime survey](http://manual.limesurvey.org/wiki/Workarounds%3a_Survey_behaviour)

I think submit button is generated, therefore I couldn't access the button to add a onclick event.

I am trying to write fileuploading validation for one of my lime servey.

Comment: Old post, but my own recent experience on adding a click event on the button was resulting in the clearing of the form. Something to do with the LS sends the data. Any any case, try $('#movenextbtn, #movesubmitbtn').click(function(){ ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding javascript to limesurvey is pretty well covered in these documents here: https://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Manipulating_a_survey_at_runtime_using_Javascript
I might be able to answer some more specific questions if you have them. Are you having trouble find where in limesurvey to put the code? Or is your issue writing the code itself? Or both? Or something else?